# What does the ternary operator mean in the code snippet using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to understand what the code below does with ternary operator. Right now it is hard to me to decode with ternary operator.

Could someone help me understand what this code does?

```
const handleSelection = React.useMemo(
    () =>
        page.map(row => {
            return singleSelect
                ? toggleSingleSelection
                    ? () => toggleSingleSelection(row)
                    : undefined
                : toggleSelection
                ? () => toggleSelection(row)
                : undefined;
            }),
      [toggleSelection]
  );
```

Comment: The difficulty you're having reading this is exactly why code like this should never have been written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page.map(row => {
  if(singleSelect && toggleSingleSelection) {
       return () => toggleSingleSelection(row)
  } else if(!singleSelect && toggleSelection) {
       return () => toggleSelection(row)
  }
})
```